# Почему при добавлении элемента в коллекцию необходимо привести тип?

Tags: c#, generics

Почему в коде ниже необходимо привести тип при добавлении элемента в коллекцию, если в ограничении на тип дженерика явно указано, какого типа может быть Т?

```
new InventoryItem() as T
```

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class InventoryItem
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Inventory<T>
    where T : InventoryItem
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _inventory = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    public Inventory()
    {
        _inventory.Add(new InventoryItem() as T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ваш код странен и вы ни в коем случае не должны так писать, потому что за маской типобезопасности скрывается ее отсутствие!

Смотрите, заголовок вашего класса:

```
public class Inventory<T> where T : InventoryItem
```

что здесь написано? А написано, что класс может получать в качестве дженерик-параметра **любого наследника `InventoryItem`**!

Т.е.:

```
public class SuperInventoryItem : InventoryItem { }
```

и где-то

```
var invertory = new Inventory<SuperInventoryItem>();
```

Угадайте что здесь произойдет? А лучше запустите и проверьте!

Надеюсь вы понимаете, что если `B` является `A`, то обратное не верно в общем случае? Именно об этом вам говорит компилятор и поэтому в общем случае `new A() as B` будет возвращать `null`!

Таким образом у вас есть 2 пути:

Если у вас в программе не предвидится никаких наследников `InventoryItem`, то вам вообще не надо вводить таких ограничений: `T : InventoryItem`, просто работайте внутри исключительно с `InventoryItem`, а не `T`. Я бы для верности тогда сделал бы класс `InventoryItem` еще и запечатанным (`sealed`).

Если у вас в программе будут наследники `InventoryItem` и класс должен уметь их создавать, то вам следует освоить паттерн "Фабрика" и передавать в конструктор `Inventory` *фабрику `InventoryItem`*, это сделает ваш код чище: класс `Inventory` в принципе не обязан знать как создаются и настраиваются любые `InventoryItem`.

Comment: Да, приведение типов от родителя к наследнику выглядит странно, когда его замечаешь. Вообще, пример написал второпях и мне казалось, он суть вопроса хорошо отражает. На самом деле у Inventory есть метода AddItem, который принимает объекты, сгенерированные фабрикой ItemFactory.Create(). Не знаю, есть ли смысл передавать ее внуть Inventory или это был пример на случай того, если объекты создаются в конструкторе? В общем, мне кажется, хорошим ответом является указание на возможность создать объект с наследником обощенного типа, вследствие чего приведение типов будет работать некорректно.

Comment: Ну это вы уже сами решите, если надо создавать внутри, то передавайте фабрику, нет – передавайте сами элементы. А в конструкторе или где – не важно, можно и в конструктор передать элемент, вместо того чтобы создавать его там внутри. Вполне возможно, что InventoryItem нельзя создать без каких-то данных, которые появляются внутри Invertory, тогда уж без передачи в него фабрики не обойтись

Comment: Ладно, я продумал вчера остаток вечера, но не понял, как передача фабрики объекта внутрь класса `Inventory` поможет с типобезопасностью. Фабрика ничего не знает об обобщенном типе, значит, мы все так же можем инициализировать дженерик производным классом, а фабрика будет выдавать нам родительские классы. Как сделать это снаружи, [понятно](https://dotnetfiddle.net/slvsTi). Но как добавлять элементы через фабрику внутри `Inventory`?

Comment: Фабрика тоже должна быть обобщенной: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G5nRog Впрочем, не совсем понятно какую задачу вы решаете, возможно, лучше будет задать отдельный вопрос по архитектуре

Comment: Понял, абстрактная фабрика - то что нужно. По архитектуре задавать вопросы смысла особого нет, это намеренное усложнение задачи, чтобы попрактиковаться с дженериками. Во славу энтерпрайза, так сказать.